# Non-printable characters missing on Javascript function in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, character-encoding, ascii

I have code below of an HTML page that includes a JS file. Function d() receives a String of 24 chars, including **3 non-printable chars** (ASCII 005) and counts how many characters are included. This number is displayed with an alert().

- **Google Chrome:** correctly displays 24 as a result.
- **Google Chrome (JS debugger):** correctly displays 24 as a result.
- **Internet Explorer 9:** correctly displays 24 as a result.
- **Internet Explorer 9 (JS debugger):** displays only 21 (24 - 3 non printable).

I really need this to work with Internet Explorer. Any ideas? THANKS

TEST.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>JavaScript Scripting</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="test.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**TEST.JS**

```
function d(a){return a.length;};
document.write("<script language=\"Javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">alert(".concat(d("a[NULL]lert(\"He[NULL]llo Worl[NULL]d\");")).concat(");</script>"));
```

Comment: Why not return just a length of the string?

Comment: Thanks. I did and issue is there. I have updated question with results.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried to escape those chars? I.e. put them as `\x05` or `\u0005`. Also, please add to the question, which version of IE do you use.

Comment: Thanks, please find solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to know *when* IE lost this bytes! But it looks like it miss them exact on split: check if IE returns true on "" == "\u0005". Try to avoid using hack like `smth +""` use toString() ( what would you get after `'Infinity' -0` ?). Or use `var i= 0; while (a.length) { substr(a, 0, 1); i+=1; //...` no IE to test, but could help.

*UPD*

[As provided by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yfce773%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) IE not in standard mode and less then 9 evaluates `"\v" == "v"` as **true**, so it could be the same with nullchar which causes the string length becomes shorter?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Very interesting the "\v" update. I am using IE9. I have updated my question, as seems that the problem is on the string received, because if I do a.length I get 21 instead of 24 in IE. And very strange: it is only failing on IE9 JS DEBUGGER, but on IE9 browser I correctly receive 24. Perhaps a charset issue?

Comment: Not even sure. If IE works fine and debugger not. Maybe debugger is every time is in non standard mode? Did you tried to check local string length with debugger?

Comment: You were right, IE9 JS debugger is, by default, on non-standard mode. Just needed to change this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Haven't found such a problem in IE8.